# Scrolling elements on FAB Speed Dial

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I am using FAB Speed Dial from angular material, and i'm wondering how to handle many menu elements. I want to make maximum 5 elements in menu and scroll to find rest. Because now not even all elements are shown.

Now all elements are shown:

[image: Now all elements are shown]

Do someone has a solution? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the material design guideline:

> As a general rule, have at least three options upon press but not more than six, including the original floating action button target. If you have two options – i.e. your floating action button only flings out one other choice – choose which action is most important. If you have more than six, users may have trouble reaching the furthest option.
>   Reduce decision fatigue by giving users the best, most distinct, and fewest options.

https://material.io/guidelines/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#buttons-floating-action-button-transitions